# Post and Get using AsyncTask

Tags: android, post, android-asynctask, get

I have to use Async Task to do a post and a get resquest in my Server. I got an error because I was doing in android 2.3 Gingerbread, and for later versions I need AsyncTask.

I have this code here :

> private class Connection extends AsyncTask {
>
> ```
>     @Override
>     protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
>         connect();
>         return null;
>     }
> ```

So, in my on create I call

> new Connection().execute();

but, the problem is I have 3 function:

postData()

getData()

How can I use doInBackground(Object... arg0) with 2 diferents, functions?

Des someone know how to do it 2 times?

Thank you

Comment: Just call all functions you want in doInBackground. Why do you think that would be a problem?

Comment: I didn't think would be a problem. I cannot call at the same time because they are called in different times in my application. I will post data just when the user input data, and I will get the result when the user finish putting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways of doing it. You could create two `AsyncTask` subclasses, one for `postData()` and another for `getData()`. Or you could create a single subclass in which you choose which operation to do depending on a parameter passed in its constructor or as a parameter to `execute(...)`. That said, you should never run `execute()` more than once for the same instance (object) of a given `AsyncTask`; create a different instance and call `execute()` on the new instance instead.

Comment: I solved the problem already: I just created an 'if' when put case 1, 2 and 3. So I created more 3 functions, when I call post , for example, I call new Connection(1).execute(); So, the function will execute is 'POst'. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Alright. If you feel that the answer helped somehow, feel free to accept it by clicking in the check icon to its left.